# Correctly modeling master-detail relationship with special detail relationship

Tags: salesforce

I have to model the following use case:

- I have record A and B related by a master-detail relationship
- I need to hold on A informations from the most recent B (let's say B it's some sort of query to an expensive data source)
- I need to hold on A the navigable reference to the most recent B (i.e. the one I selected as data source for A)

How can I model this? Is the only possibility to go through code / a custom VisualForce controller to make this link navigable ?

Comment: You may also want put down the business ask, cause this isn't clear what you're trying to do

Comment: If I understand correctly you could add a lookup field on A to Object B with a workflow that sets that value to object B record when a new one is inserted or whatever criteria you use to determine the latest b record.